# How to add product filter dropdown in woo commerce order page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

**How to add filter by product in woo commerce order page in admin side?**
[image: filter by product]

Answer (score 1):

**Here is solution for above questions**

```php
// Custom function to get the product names, that appear in the existing orders
function get_product_names() {
 global $wpdb;

 return $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT DISTINCT order_item_name 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
    WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item'
");
} 

function action_restrict_manage_posts( $post_type, $which ) {   
   global $pagenow;

// Compare
if ( $post_type === 'shop_order' && $pagenow === 'edit.php' ) {
    $filter_id  = 'filter_product';
    $current    = isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) ? $_GET[$filter_id] : '';

    // Create a drop-down list 
    echo '<select name="' . $filter_id . '">
    <option value="">' . __( 'Filter by product', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>';

    foreach ( get_product_names() as $product_name ) {          
        printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $product_name, $product_name === $current ? '" selected="selected"' : '', ucfirst( $product_name ) );
    }
    
    echo '</select>';
}
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'action_restrict_manage_posts', 10, 2 );

function action_pre_get_posts( $query ) {   
   global $pagenow, $post_type, $wpdb;

    $filter_id = 'filter_product';

    // Compare
    if ( $query->is_admin && $pagenow === 'edit.php' && $post_type === 'shop_order' && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && $_GET[$filter_id] != '' ) {

    // Get all orderIDs in which the product name occurs
     $order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT DISTINCT order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
        WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_name = '%s'
        ",  esc_attr( $_GET[$filter_id] ) 
    ) );

    // Set the new "meta query"
    $query->set( 'post__in', $order_ids );

    // Set "posts per page"
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );

    // Set "paged"
    $query->set( 'paged', ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 
) );
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'action_pre_get_posts', 10, 1 );
```